# 電子書籍のマルチメディア対応について

Tags: android, html5, web-audio

最近は電子書籍のマルチメディア化が進んでいるようなので、音声や動画を貼り付けた電子書籍を大手のアマゾンと楽天koboで自己出版しようとしました。
アマゾンジャパンはまだマルチメディア非対応、楽天koboは可能との事でしたので、試しに楽天 kobo で下記のように Audio Control を貼り付けた電子書籍を作成しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>第一章　My town, Maycomb </h3>


<audio src="../Audio/ala10_01_01.mp3" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
<br/>

<span style="text-decoration: underline;">
<span style="font-weight: bold;">1-1</span><br/></span>Maycomb was a tired, old town, even in nineteen thirty two&#160;when I first knew it.<br/>私が初めて知った１９３２年においてさえ、メイコームはくたびれた古い町だった。<div><br/><div><br/>
```

以降Audio Controlを150件ほど張り付けています。

ＩＯＳ用及びアンドロイド用のkobo電子書籍リーダアプリでブックを開いた所、iPadでは上手く動作し、Audio再生ボタンも表示され再生も問題有りませんでしたが、Androidスマホやタブレットでブックを開くと、所どころでAudio再生ボタンが表示されません。この場合でも、ボタンのあるべき場所をタッチするとボタンが表示されます。

何が原因と考えるられるでしょうか？
ご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 質問文を、分かりやすくなるように修正いたしました。意図とずれてしまっていたら、ロールバック(差し戻し)をお願いできますでしょうか。

Comment: 他の人が状況を再現できるよう、行った具体的な手順や参考にした資料、問題が起きない部分と起きる部分の違いなどを本文を編集して追記してください。

Comment: @YukiInoue さん、意図がずれてしまっている可能性があると思うのでしたら、まずはコメントで投稿者の意図を確認すべきではないでしょうか? コメント機能さえ使ったことのない投稿者にいきなり「ロールバック(差し戻し)をお願い」しても、なんのことやらわからない可能性も高いでしょう。

Comment: @OOPer 確かに、その通りでした。 i) いきなりロールバックと言われても何のことやら ii) 編集が怪しいのならば、コメントでそれを確認するべき。 …以降、気をつけます。

Comment: @YukiInoue さん、返信ありがとうございます。本質的な部分はご理解いただいているようなので、私の心配の方が杞憂なのかもしれません。色々な意見を直接受け止める立場になって大変でしょうが頑張ってください。